# Can I change the instance variable using ajax in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have used ajax to get the object from controller.

```
  $('#city').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/courses/index",
      type: "GET",
      data: {city: $('#city').val() },
      success: function(responseData) {
        alert(responseData);
      }
    });
```

So the `responseData` is the json format collection of the courses.

Currently, I have a html code: `<%= @courses.first.name %>`

How to modify the `@courses` instance which the result is the responseData of ajax.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the instance variable, because that belongs to the *instance* of the Ruby class you're using.

Using ajax invokes a new instance of your respective classes (on the server); javascript only works with the front-end view (HTML code / [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)), so you have to populate that with the response:

```
$(document).on('change', '#city', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/courses/index",
      type: "GET",
      data: {city: $('#city').val() },
      success: function(responseData) {
        course = JSON.parse(responseData);
        $(".element").html(course.name);
      }
    });
});
```

Without knowing which data you're expecting back etc, it's kind of tough to know  how to "parse" your data. However, the important thing to note is that you should **not** be trying to change the `ERB`, instead identify the `html` and replace it with the JSON you receive back.

Also, you'll need to use something like JSON.parse to create a workable object in your javascript (which you can then use to populate your page with).

Comment: Thanks for you explain.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to POST the information back to the rails application via Ajax.